# how to show agregate on where clause ? or is there any other way to solve this

Tags: sql, sql-server

the continue for my question.

I want to show agregate function on where clause. but an error occured.

my table :

[image]

I have tried like this (which method is to show total purchase for sales_id after where clause.

```
select * from customer where customer_id = ANY (
    select customer_id from sales where sales_id = ANY (
        select sales_id from sales_detail where sum(total) < (
            select sum(total) from sales_detail where sales_id = (
                select sales_id from sales where customer_id = (
                    select customer_id from customer where name = 'steven'
                    ) 
                )
            ) group by sales_id
        )
    )
```

and I have tried like this (which the number of purchase was within sub query)

```
select * from customer where customer_id = ANY (
    select customer_id from sales where sales_id = ANY (
        select sales_id from sales_detail where (
            select sum(total) from sales_detail where sales_id = (
                select sales_id from sales where customer_id = (
                    select customer_id from customer where name = 'steven'
                    )
                )
            )
            < ANY (
            select sum(total) as number_of_purchase, sales_id /*, sales_id*/ from sales_detail group by sales_id
            ) group by sales_id
        )
    )
```

I have show the number of purchases for those 5 sales id

```
select sum(total) as number_of_purchase, sales_id /*, sales_id*/  
from sales_detail 
group by sales_id
```

and the result was like this

[image]

> what I want is

I want to show 'costumer name' and 'costumer id' where the 'number of purchase' is more than 'the number of purchase' of 'steven'

**number of purchase of steven is 3**

so the result should be like this

```
| name | customer_id|
| Clark | c03 |
| Josh | c05 |
```

**because total purchase all of them was more than 3**
**you can look from result above**

thx.

Comment: do you know about `HAVING` clause?

Comment: no I just begin to learn about sql, especialy sql server. Oke thx for your advice I'll began surfing about Having Clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select customer_id , name ,sum(total)
from customer ,sales_detail d, Sales s 
where d.sales_id = s.sales_id
and  customer_id = s.customer_id
having sum(total) > ( select sum(total)
                      from customer , sales s, sales_detail d
                      where customer_id = s.customer_id
                      and d.sales_id = s.sales_id 
                      and name = 'Steven')
```

Comment: You are not really recommending using this ancient join syntax, are you?

Answer (score 1):

**Thx all. for your advice I got it.**

i just recreate the query and became like this. :D

```
select * from customer where customer_id = ANY (
    select customer_id from sales where sales_id = ANY (
        select sales_id from sales_detail
            group by sales_id
            having sum(sales_detail.total) > (
                select sum(total) from sales_detail where sales_id = (
                    select sales_id from sales where customer_id = (
                        select customer_id from customer where name = 'steven'
                        )
                    )
                )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Do you know about a join?

Comment: yes I know. this is a task. and I have to do it without using join or inner join :D .. but thx for your advice. using Inner join is more simple than using sub query.

Comment: yups, he purpose to make us begin understanding subquery. well studied from school only get the basic. while we are in a comunity, like this. maybe I'll get more experience from you all cause I'll face real problem not only theory. and sory I answer my own question for my future references. :D

Comment: I think it's good to learn it this way. Many beginners tend to join all tables before even thinking the query through and then they struggle with aggregates from different tables or duplicate rows they must get rid of with DISTINCT later. Using subqueries instead makes you create the query step by step.